# Access local folder with native messaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension, shared-directory, chrome-native-messaging

Can a local/shared folder can be accessed from website in chrome using chrome extension- native messaging?
if so how?

Comment: Yes. See [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) documentation. You use it in an extension to launch a separate utility. That utility runs like any OS program so it has access to file system. You can write that utility yourself in node.js or any other language. There are many examples.

Comment: But we cannot do it directly from chrome extension without using any intermediate utility. right?

Comment: Yes. In the future extensions might be able to use the upcoming Native File System API.